# Is there any tools which can convert any strings to UTF-8 encoded values in Linux?

Tags: linux

Is there any tools which can convert any strings to UTF-8 encoded values in Linux? Or any website is also OK.

Comment: Do you really mean UTF-8 encoded? You can do that with recode, you must know the original encoding, though, e.g. for Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) you do `recode l1..u8`.

Answer (score 2):

You should try iconv:

`cat yourfile | iconv -f latin -t utf-8 > yourfileINUTF8`

You only need to know from what encode you are converting.

To discover the original encode of your file you can do.

`file -i yourfile`

And look for "charset="

Answer (score 1):

This is basically Onilton Maciel answer, except that it finds original encoding itself.

`iconv -f $(file -b --mime-encoding yourfile) -t utf-8 < yourfile > youroutput`